# How to suppress GKS messages to REPL?

Tags: julia, julia-plots, gr

I'm doing some plotting with `Plots` and the GR backend.  I have some `NaN`s in the data that I use for ribbon and filled plots.  This results in gaps in the traces, which is fine and by design, and a lot of this message:

```
GKS: Number of points is invalid in routine FILLAREA
```

The actual plots come out fine.  The message itself is problematic because large blocks of these mess up the REPL output.  There are things I can do to skip the `NaN`s and avoid this problem but sometimes I just want to put together some plotting code quickly in the course of debugging something and don't want to jump through 15 hoops to avoid GR's message barf.  Is there some quick way to disable GKS warnings?